# Получение раскладки клавиатуры на macOS

Tags: python, macos, клавиатура

Задача - получить текущую раскладку клавиатуры в MacOS(русская/английская).
Считается, что может быть только 1 или 2 раскладки. Видел только варианты с win32api. Очевидно, не подходит.
Из идиотских вариантов конечно же в голову залезла идея через какой нибудь pyautogui смотреть в нужной области какой флажок, но это полная жуть)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Determine OS X keyboard layout ("input source") in the terminal/a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21597804/4279)

Comment: через ctypes, [посмотрите _get_layout() метод](https://github.com/openstenoproject/plover/blob/master/plover/oslayer/osxkeyboardlayout.py)